# Load map as a key from properties file

Tags: java, collections, java-8

How I can get a map as key from properties file and load in a list. For example I want to create a hashmap of student information from properties file. Property file can be like

```
<map name=student1>
<value key=name>abc</value>
<value key=age>12</value>
<value key=gender>male</value>

<map name=student2>
<value key=name>xyz</value>
<value key=age>15</value>
<value key=gender>female</value>

...
```

I want to create the list of all these map using key like student1, student2 etc. How can we do it in simple java 8 project using properties file in a single load. I am sorry if I am asking any repeated question. I tried to search for my solution but didn't get it. Please help with the link if same question answered before.

Comment: This looks like XML, not a properties file.

Comment: @Holger , i write the values just for understanding. We can pass properties as XML also. If you have any other way your suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: The point is, you said “*I tried to search for my solution but didn't get it*”, but apparently, you searched for the wrong terms. If you want to parse an XML file, you have to search for “XML”, not for “properties file”. Otherwise, it’s not surprising that you didn’t find matching Q&As.

Comment: @holger why do you think a properties file cannot be in xml form

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question correctly, you want to unmarshall the XML configuration into a Map<String, User>, where User has arbitrary fields.

Your config file is missing closure of the map nodes.
Once you have it in the following format, you will be able to easily automate the decoding process:

```
<Config>
  <map name="student1">
    <value key="name">abc</value>
    <value key="age">12</value>
    <value key="gender">male</value>
  </map>

  <map name="student2">
    <value key="name">xyz</value>
    <value key="age">15</value>
    <value key="gender">female</value>
  </map>
</Config>
```

You could create your custom marshaller using javax.xm.parsers solutions:

```
        try {
        final File configFile = Paths.get("C:/Development/file.xml").toFile();
        final DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        final DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        final Document doc = dBuilder.parse(configFile);

        final NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();
        if (nodeList.getLength() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Config is empty or incorrect.");
        }

        final NodeList elements = nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes();

        
        final Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
            final Node item = elements.item(i);
            if (!"map".equals(item.getNodeName())) {
                continue;
            }

            final String key = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();


            final NodeList childNodes = item.getChildNodes();

            String name;
            String age;
            String gender;

            for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                final Node childItem = childNodes.item(j);
                if (!"value".equals(childItem.getNodeName())) {
                    continue;
                }

                final String fieldName = childItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue();
                final String fieldValue = childItem.getNodeValue();
                switch (fieldName) {
                    case "name":
                        name = childItem.getNodeValue();
                        break;
                    case "age":
                        age = childItem.getNodeValue();
                        break;
                    case "gender":
                        gender = childItem.getNodeValue();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown user field %s", fieldName));

                }
            }
            
            users.put(key, new User(name, age, gender));
        }
    } catch (final ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error during config parsing");
    }
```

EDIT:
Due to comments under the main post and my inability to write there, I will write here:
Config properties file is a commonly used structure of key-value pairs serialized into file as in following example:

```
property.name=value
other.property.name=value
```

XML file is form of data structure as well, although the possibilities for XML files are wider and provide more data flexibility as well as objects serialization. Your configuration can be stored in properties format, XML, JSON, etc. However the type of your data suggests usage of more complex data storage structure than properties